# How to take Cassandra snapshot?

Tags: cassandra

I have seen how Cassandra is taking Snapshot for backup. But I'm not clearly understand what happens if we format entire drive after taking snapshot. Whether we are able to restore entire cassandra data which was taken snapshot earlier as cassandra takes snapshot as hard-link?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cassandra snapshot is just a hard-link, so, another filename for same data. If you destroy your data, e.g. by disk formatting - you of course will destroy snapshot too. If you want using snapshot for backup properties you need to store snapshot and database schema in safe place, right after creation - e.g. copy it somewhere, e.g. for AWS S3 using [this tool](https://github.com/tbarbugli/cassandra_snapshotter)